# Why does my slimscroll have issues when the height is set at a percentage as opposed to a fixed value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using [this slimscroll library](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) to display a better looking scroll bar for some divs on my page. I noticed that if I set the height of my scrollbar class to a fixed value (i.e. '500px', '80vh' etc.) then if the content does not overflow, the scrollbar will not be present and if it does, then it will appear. It works great.

However this solution doesn't work well because I need the div that encompasses the scrollbar to take up 100% of the parent div. However when I do that, the scrollbar will appear even if the content does not overflow the container.

Does anyone know a solution where I can set the height of the scrollbar to be 100% and have it behave so that it only appear when content overflows the parent container?

HTML

```
           <div class="s12 m12 l12 row-90 m-b-0 rail-row">
                <div class="card-scroll m-r-10">
                    <ul class="top-list">
                        ///adds a series of divs based on data from back end
                        {{#each ins in selectedInstruction}}
                            <li>{{> Print_job printJobArgs ins true true}}</li>
                        {{/each}}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JS

```
$('.card-scroll').slimScroll({
        size: '8px',
        height: '100%',
    });
    $(".slimScrollBar").hide()
```

When the page gets loaded, slimscroll encompasses the div with the class 'card-scroll' in a div and adds html to make its scrollbar appear.

Comment: Could you, please, explain why you need to set a 100% height ? Also, could you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: I think the height value should be in px, set height dynamically using javascript to the div based on the window height after page load and resize events. And by default the scrollbar will appear only if the content overflows.